# ¿Como manejar impresoras y etiquetas Zebra con C#?

Tags: c#

estoy haciendo una aplicación Windows Forms con C#, pero me surgio un problema, en la aplicación se necesita que se impriman etiquetas con impresoras de la marca Zebra, pero no le entiendo muy bien, a lo que me refiero es. ¿Si se puede manipular la etiqueta desde la aplicacion poniendole los datos que yo necesito?, es decir, los datos los elige el usuario y le en imprimir y sale la etiqueta, alguien me puede orientar.

Comment: La verdad solo he leído preguntas al respecto en Stack Overflow en inglés; si no lo has hecho aún, busca `c# zebra print barcode` en Google. Cuando tengas mas información, [edit] la pregunta con lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede usar la clase `PrintDocument` con esta puedes enviar texto definiendo la posicion donde quieres imprimirlo, no tendras diseñador donde definir la etiqueta pero si puedes enviar el texto a impresion.

Quizas debas trabjar mas a prueba y error , pero para eso existen las impresoras virtuales en pdf, cuando veas que este correcto pasas a imprimir en la impresora fisica

[Información general sobre el componente PrintDocument (formularios Windows Forms)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/printdocument-component-overview-windows-forms)

basicamente defines las lineas

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
pd.Print();
```

y luego en el evento usas el DrawString() indicando la posicion del texto en la pagina

```
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
  //resto codigo
  ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black,
           leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());

}
```

aqui lo simplifico analiza el codigo completo del articulo